# Solve Recurrence Equation: ()=(−4)+^2

Tags: asymptotics, recurrence-relation, big-o-notation

I'm trying to practice recurrence equations, so I'm trying to solve this typology by unfolding method.
I was wondering if what I write below was correct and obviously the result:

$T(n) = n^2 + T(n-4) = n^2 + [n^2 + T(n - 8)] = n^2 + n^2 +[n^2 + T(n-12)] = n^2 + n^2 + n^2 + [n^2 + T(n-16)] = ...$

In general we can say that $T(n)$ is done in the following way:

$$T(n) = \sum_{i=0}^{\frac{n-5}{4}} n^2 + T(n-(4+4i))$$

Note that the summation takes that form because $T(n-(4+4i)) = T(1) = 1$ when $( −(4+4) ) = 1$ which occurs for $i = \frac{n-5}{4}$

So it would be more correct to write T(n) as follows:

$$T(n) = \sum_{i=0}^{\frac{n-5}{4}} n^2  + 1 $$

At this point we leave out the constant 1 (which asymptotically is irrelevant) and focus on the summation :

$$T(n) = \sum_{i=0}^{\frac{n-5}{4}} n^2 = n^2\sum_{i=0}^{\frac{n-5}{4}} 1 = n^2 ( \frac{n-5}{4} +1) = O(n^3)$$

So overall we can say that :

$$T(n) = O(n^3)$$

Comment: Unfortunately, your development is wrong from the beginning.  Should be $T(n) = n^2 + T(n-4) = n^2 + [\color{red}{(n-4)}^2 + T(n - 8)] =\cdots$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the recurrence only involves values four units apart, we rewrite with $n=4m$:

$$T(4m)=T(4m-4)+(4m)^2$$

or

$$U(m)=U(m-1)+16m^2.$$

The solution is

$$U(m)=U(0)+16\sum_{k=1}^mk^2= U(0)+16\frac{m(m+1)(2m+1)}6$$ by the well-known formula for the sum of squares. From this

$$T(n)=T(0)+\frac{n(n+2)(n+4)}{12}$$ which is obviously $O(n^3)$.

---

Note that this result holds for $n$ multiple of $4$ only. For $n$ of the form $4m+i$, replace $T(0)$ by $T(i)$.